# Drools Unable to resolve ObjectType during ant build

Tags: java, ant, build, drools

I am using DroolsCompilerAntTask for the ant build and I am getting the below error during the build

```
rules:
 [compiler] Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Result' : [Rule name='Test']
```

For the rule file I have

```
package rules

import com.drools.info.*; 

dialect "java"

rule "Test"   
    when
        $r:Result(total == Result.ONE  )
    then
        System.out.println( "Test Complete." );
end
```

build.xml

```
<!-- rule -->
 <path id="drools.path" >
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/libs">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>  
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/build/rules" /> <- this is my path to compiled class files. If I exclude this line I got the above error. If I include this line then I got the (Access is denied) error. Either way is errored out. Are there permanent solution to this?

 </path>

 <path id="compile.classpath"> 
 </path>

 <taskdef name="compiler" classname="org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask" classpathref="drools.path" />

  <target name="rules" >
    <compiler
      binformat="package" 
      srcdir="${basedir}/src/rules"
      tofile="${basedir}/build"
      classpathref="compile.classpath" >
      <include name="*.drl" />
      <include name="*.brl" />
      <include name="*.xml" />
      <include name="*.dslr" />
    </compiler>
  </target>
```

Where the Result is a class object from the com.drool.info.Result
I think when I compile the rules I did not add the class file along with the rule may cause this? or are there a way to tell that the ant rule compiler the class file is related? If that is the issue how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Compiling a .drl file is similar to compiling a Java file in several respects. Most importantly, all classes used in the .drl must either be in the same package as the .drl, or they must be imported. Importing, however, merely resolves the name space - to get at the structure of the class, the .class file of the class must be availabe. How else could the compiler know what the field references mean?

Make sure to have the .class files or a .jar file containing them are in the class path.

Comment: can you give like an example? I mean how do I include the .class file in ant with the drl or whatever is needed

Comment: What about classpath and classpathref in the taskdef? If you are using ant, you need to know about the attributes defining stuff.

Comment: The reason i asked is because when I add the class to the path I got this error. C:\Users\John\workspacetools\build.xml:65: RuleBaseTask failed: C:\Users\John\workspace\build (Access is denied)